# Faking a Linux environment without chroot

Tags: linux, bash, path, computing-environment

For a university project I want to test a C++11 program on a 32-core machine. Unfortunately the machine has Ubuntu 12.04 with GCC 4.6 installed (we need GCC 4.7 because of some C++11 threading features). 
In such an environment I would normally run a chroot with a custom linux (say a debootstrap with Ubuntu 12.10). Since we don't get root access on the machine we can't use chroot.

So far I have prepared a run-time environment using debootstrap for our code, I compiled it in the debootstrap environemnt. Then copied it onto the server (using rsync). 
In order to run our C++ code I set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH to

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=~/debootstrap/usr/lib/:~/debootstrap/lib64/:~/debootstrap/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:~/debootstrap/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

and so far our code seems to run. I'm however stuck with our python code. It doesn't seem to be sufficient to set the paths manually.

```
export PYTHONPATH=~/debootstrap/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:~/debootstrap/usr/lib/python2.7:~/debootstrap/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2:~/debootstrap/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk:~/debootstrap/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload:~/debootstrap/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:~/debootstrap/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7:~/debootstrap/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL:~/debootstrap/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0:~/debootstrap/usr/lib/python2.7
```

Executing our script results in

```
ImportError: No module named _path
```

Is there an easier way to accomplish a "fake"-chroot than just overriding and creating environment variables?

Note I need python since we created a custom C++-Python module in order to run our tests. Maybe I should create two questions from this.

Comment: What about downloading the newer version of gcc (or the source) and installing it as a use in your home directory (if you have one)? Well, how big is this program?

Comment: Did you also try to set PYTHONHOME?

Comment: What's the standard location for PYTHONHOME? Is it /usr/lib/python2.7?

Comment: Nick: it's easier to create a sandboxed environment because replacing gcc requires also the replacement of glibc (or a recompilation)  which then also has very broad side effects.

Comment: Have you tried fakeroot or [fakeroot-ng](http://fakeroot-ng.lingnu.com/index.php/Home_Page)? You might be able to coerce a `chroot` under `fakeroot-ng`...

Comment: There's actually a package called fakechroot. Which allows for the creation of a "fake" chroot environment (exactly what we need actually). I'm however hesitant since both fakeroot and fakechroot can produce a significant performance overhead since all system calls are redirected..

Comment: @Nick: Pascal stated a requirement to use a 32-core machine.  Not many people have one of _those_ at home.

Comment: @Pascal: when you respond to a comment (in a new comment), it’s conventional to mention the author’s name, preceded by a “@” symbol, as in “@Nick”.  That way he gets notified.  See the **Replying in comments** paragraphs of [the **Comment formatting** section](http://superuser.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) of the Markdown Editing Help page.

Comment: Have you tried using `virtualenv` to manage your python environment?

Comment: @Pascal, oops. I must have glazed over it and read it as 32-bit. Even so, I think I'm out of my league.

Comment: @allquixotic fakechroot seems to work but we had to take special care of the symlinks in the directories. I'm a bit unsure about the performance overhead though.

Comment: @DarthAndroid: virtualenv is a bit problematic since ubuntu does some weird stuff to their python libraries... We managed to run some of the libraries but only in a fachechroot environment after taking care of the symlinks. 
For the time being we just request the python libraries on the target machine...

Comment: @Cedric For the python problem. Pip install --user <pythonmodules> definitely helped ;)